# Elasticsearch to Spark Stream

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, streaming

So my goal is to read data from Elasticsearch to spark (for streaming) and then training the ML model, i found out its not supported but how to get data to spark from Elasticsearch every time new data sent to Elasticsearch from some other source to same index like after every 10 minutes.

Comment: You will have to poll your indices in ElasticSearch with some time predicate that is between now()-10m and now(). May be there is a timestamp that indicates when your data was ingested or something similar.  This is the only way you can get delta's that you can extract and process.

Comment: is there anything else which we use like some alert (if data inserted in elasticsearch) instead of using time

Comment: A CDC like solution would be needed. I am not sure if there is a direct CDC out of the box for ElasticSearch that can be used though